# Is there a way to know the exact orientation of the phone?

Tags: android, android-camera

Usually, there's a compass and an accelerometer on a typical smartphone these days. So, using information from these sensors can we recreate the whole orientation in which the photo was taken?
I mean like if you open the compass app on your phone, it firstly states the direction you are looking ([link](https://ibb.co/5nNj0mW)), how lifted or tilted is your phone in front direction ( I don't know how to state it in a better way) ([link](https://ibb.co/Lh1gk14)) and how much is it titled in sideways ([link](https://ibb.co/B4Pr5V4)). Does it cover 3 degrees of freedom (i guess)?
Is it enough information to recreate that orientation of the phone?

Also if you think it's not the right place to ask such a question, can you comment where should I ask this question?

Answer (score 0):

Recording sensor values, it would be possible to restore phone direction in which photo was taken. Some fundamental XR apps(e.g. Google Street View) are actually doing such.

**Device rotation**

There is a handy helper function, [SensorManager.getRotationMatrix](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#getRotationMatrix(float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D)) exactly for that purpose. Giving magnetic field and gravity sensor-values, you can obtain the device rotation matrix(=complete set of orthogonal 3d basis vectors) which is enough for you to reproduce phone direction afterwards.

**Camera orientation**

In some cases camera's up direction may be different from device's up direction due to screen orientation changes(portrait or landscape, locked or auto-rotate). So if you handle raw camera inputs, you may need to record screen orientation too. See [Display.getRotation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display#getRotation()).